# Cakephp 3.6: Multiple foreign keys between 2 tables

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am new developer in **CakePHP** and PHP.

> I have 2 tables: `Tasks` and `Users`.

Among others `Tasks` has these foreign keys linked to `Users` table: `Assigned_from`, `Assigned_to`, `Created_by`.

So in `UsersTable.php` I have inserted these lines:

---

Function initialize :

```
$this->hasMany('TasksTo', [
            'foreignKey' => 'assigned_to',
            'className' => 'Tasks'
        ]);
$this->hasMany('TasksFrom', [
            'foreignKey' => 'assigned_From',
            'className' => 'Tasks'
        ]);
$this->hasMany('TasksBy', [
            'foreignKey' => 'created_by',
            'className' => 'Tasks'
        ]);
```

Function buildrules :

```
$rules->add($rules->existsIn(['assigned_to'], 'TasksTo'));
$rules->add($rules->existsIn(['assigned_from'], 'TasksFrom'));
$rules->add($rules->existsIn(['created_by'], 'TasksBy'));
```

---

Accordingly in **TasksTable.php** :
Function initialize :

```
$this->belongsTo('UsersTo', [
        'foreignKey' => 'assigned_to',
        'className' => 'Users'
    ]);
$this->belongsTo('UsersFrom', [
        'foreignKey' => 'assigned_from',
        'className' => 'Users'
    ]);
$this->belongsTo('UsersBy', [
        'foreignKey' => 'created_by',
        'className' => 'Users'
    ]);
```

Function buildrules :

```
$rules->add($rules->existsIn(['assigned_to'], 'UsersTo'));
$rules->add($rules->existsIn(['created_by'], 'UsersBy'));
$rules->add($rules->existsIn(['assigned_from'], 'UsersFrom'));
```

So in order to show this information in the User view I have added these lines in **UsersController.php** :

```
public function view($id = null)
{
    $user = $this->Users->get($id,[
        'contain' => ['TasksTo', 'TasksFrom', 'TasksBy']
    ]); 
    $this->set('user', $user);
}
```

How I can modify the `view.ctp` in order to display all this information?

Here is the current code:

```
<div class="related">
    <h4><?= __('Related Tasks') ?></h4>
    <?php if (!empty($user->tasks)): ?>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"><?= __('Priority') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= __('Name') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= __('Instructions') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= __('Date_start') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= __('Date_end') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= __('Total_minutes') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= __('Assigned_from') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= __('Customer_id') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= __('Progress') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= __('Shared_folder_path') ?></th>
            <th scope="col" class="actions"><?= __('Actions') ?></th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($user->tasks as $tasks): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= h($tasks->priority) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($tasks->name) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($tasks->instructions) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($tasks->date_start) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($tasks->date_end) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($tasks->total_minutes) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($tasks->assigned_from) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($tasks->customer_id) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($tasks->progress) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($tasks->shared_folder_path) ?></td>
            <td class="actions">
                <?= $this->Html->link(__('View'), ['controller' => 'Tasks', 'action' => 'view', $tasks->id]) ?>
                <?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['controller' => 'Tasks', 'action' => 'edit', $tasks->id]) ?>
                <?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), ['controller' => 'Tasks', 'action' => 'delete', $tasks->id], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $tasks->id)]) ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `hasMany` associations will be available as lowercase and underscored version of association name:

```
$user->tasks_to   //TaskTo association
$user->tasks_from //TasksFrom association
$user->tasks_by   //TasksBy association
```

So, to display these data in your view, you need to loop each of these associations separately, eg:

```
<?php foreach($user->tasks_to as $task): ?>
    <td><?= h($task->priority) ?></td>
    <td><?= h($task->name) ?></td>
    <td><?= h($task->instructions) ?></td>
    <td><?= h($task->date_start) ?></td>
    <td><?= h($task->date_end) ?></td>
    <!-- and so on... -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

More info can be found in CakePHP docs:

[**CakePHP 3 Conventions**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html)

[**CakePHP 3 Associations**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html)

Comment: Thank you! but I have 2 questions what happen if `$user->tasks_to` is null? Then I won't display anything right? even if there are values in the other fields? And how I can display the user's name and not the id in the $task->assigned_from, $task->assigned_to etc?